# Will a step down converter from 220V to 110V-100W "toast" a Nintendo Wii?

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-wii

I was checking the normal AC 110V to DC adaptor that comes with my Nintendo Wii and it says "52W" but my only options for buying are 50W, 60W or 100W.

I am assuming the 50W won't be enough so I don't know if I should buy 60W or 100W.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this belongs at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ more than Gaming; we're not the mad scientists. :)

Comment: Yeah I was just wondering if some Nintendo gamer has already had this good/bad experience... but I think you may be right, I'll probably try over there as well, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd probably be fine with either a 60W or a 100W step-down converter - if the Wii power brick draws at most 52W, the transformer has to be able to supply at least that amount as well.  This means that either 60W or 100W would be sufficient, but 50W would be pushing it.

However, I *highly* suggest just buying a new power brick for the country you live in.  Replacement power supplies for consoles tend to be fairly cheap, and you're much more likely to end up with something that has been tested and works properly with your device.

When shopping for transformers to take my DS with me to Europe, I found that many people reported the transformers didn't work properly with their electronics.  Buying a local DS power adapter worked like a charm, though.  Best of all, it worked with 110V as well (just requires a plug adapter) so I was able to use it after I returned to the US.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing would be to buy a legit Nintendo adapter. If this really isn't an option than anything 52W or over should do since the amount of power the device draws is the limits the incoming amount. This is why an adapter usually says something like '1 A max' which means it can support up to one ampère of current.

Since P = U*I (or wattage is voltage times amperage) the maximum current the original adapter can supply would be about 2 A. Any higher wattage adapters can supply more, but way more is unnecessary.

Comment: thanks! great answer, but I chose the other answer because the elaboration and example, sorry